# Не добавляются элементы из JSON в массив

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Выдает ошибку. Не пойму в чем проблема.

**JSON**

```
{
  "news": [
    {
      "photo": "./img/img-news/header-background.jpg",
      "article": "Проект «Краснодог»",
      "text": "Проверка текста, который я написал и составил 1."
    },
    {
      "photo": "",
      "article": "Проект «Форум добрых дел»",
      "text": "Сегодня я вам с радостью сообщаю, что работа выполнена!"
    }
  ]
}
```

**JSON**

```
function News() {
    this.newsItems = [];
    this.getJsonItem();
}

News.prototype.getJsonItem = function () {
    $.getJSON('./news.json', function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
            this.newsItems.push(data.news[i]);
        }
    });
};

News.prototype.printArr = function () {
    console.log(this.newsItems);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var news = new News();
    news.printArr();
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас контекст (`this`) внутри `$.getJSON()` - не тот что вы ожидаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как в комментарии указал @MedvedevDev, вы некоррекно используете `this`
На вашем месте получив такую ошибку, я бы сначала посмотрел, а прилетают ли данные с сервера?

```
News.prototype.getJsonItem = function () {
    $.getJSON('./news.json', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // for (var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
        //     this.newsItems.push(data.news[i]);
        // }
    });
};
```

В итоге убеждаемся, что данные приходят нормально
[image: скрин]

Далее решаем эту проблему через замыкание `self` (имя переменной на свой выбор)

```
News.prototype.getJsonItem = function () {
    let self = this;
    $.getJSON('./data.json', function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
            self.newsItems.push(data.news[i]);
        }
    });
};
```

Либо, применяя синтаксис ES-2015, в коллбэке запроса использовать "стрелочную" функцию

```
News.prototype.getJsonItem = function () {
    $.getJSON('./data.json', (data) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
            this.newsItems.push(data.news[i]);
        }
    });
};
```

В данном случае в массив данные будут добавляться, но вы не сможете их увидеть в вашем варианте кода, т.к. это АСИНХРОННЫЙ запрос. Вы пытаетесь прочесть массив `newsItems` до того, как в него будут загружены данные.

Поэтому здесь можно использовать коллбэк

```
News.prototype.getJsonItem = function (callback) {
    if(typeof callback !== 'function'){
        callback = function(){};
    }
    $.getJSON('./data.json', (data) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
            this.newsItems.push(data.news[i]);
        }
        callback();
    });
};
```

А чтобы распечатать их, можно модифицировать конструктор, например так

```
function News() {
    var self = this;
    this.newsItems = [];
    this.getJsonItem(function(){
        self.printArr();
    });
}
```

И в инициализации класса тоже немного поправить

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var news = new News();
});
```

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы я в каждой новой функции мог обращаться к newsItems?

Comment: Для этого лучше изменить алгоритм инициализации всего приложения. Например, сделать метод `News.prototipe.init`, вызвать этот метод после загрузки данных, и весь функцилнал, который зависит от этих данных (который хотели поместить в `$(document).ready` поместить в метод `init`